# Ignore flowtype error when using specific pattern

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I'm trying to use typescript together with flowtype in a transition period where everything is changing to typescript. However, flowtype is giving me an error, when I try to import declarations from a typescript file in a regular js|jsx file. I get the usual `Cannot resolve module '*.tsx`. Is it possible to ignore this flow error globally without having to use $FlowFixMe above my import statements?

This is giving flow errors, that I want to supress:

```
import foo from 'foobar.tsx';
```

Answer (score 0):

That is likewise an error in TypeScript. Depending on your module loader/bundler's extension resolution, use either

```
import foo from 'foobar';
```

or

```
import foo from 'foobar.js';
```

Since you are using JSX it's worth noting that

```
import foo from 'foobar.jsx';
```

is also incorrect.